# Error in Postman request - deserialization

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

This is in the POSTMAN request body:

```
{
    "roles":  
        [
            {
                "role_id": "TEST1",
                "role_name": "Для тестов"
            },
            {
                "role_id": "TEST3",
                "role_name": "Для тестов
            }
        ]
}
```

Model as it is :

```
public class Role 
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "role_id")]
    public string role_id { get; set; }


    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "role_name")]
    public string role_name { get; set; }

    
}
```

Controller api-method  - an Error appeared in Request

```
HttpPost("[action]/")]
public ActionResult<UserReply> SetRoleMessage(string message_text, List<Role> roles)
{
               //CODE
}
```

HERE is Postman results with an Error :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You send in an object with a property "roles" which is an array. But what your controller expects is that you send in an array.

Update your body to

```
[
    {
        "role_id": "TEST1",
        "role_name": "Для тестов"
    },
    {
        "role_id": "TEST3",
        "role_name": "Для тестов"
    }
]
```

As a side note, I would also use `[FromQuery]` and `[FromBody]` in your controller method to make more clear what is what:

```
public ActionResult<UserReply> SetRoleMessage([FromQuery] string message_text, [FromBody] List<Role> roles)
```

Answer (score 0):

The JSON you provided in the request body has a syntax error. The `role_name` property in the second role object is not closed properly with a double quotation mark.

```
{
    "roles": [
        {
            "role_id": "TEST1",
            "role_name": "Для тестов"
        },
        {
            "role_id": "TEST3",
            "role_name": "Для тестов"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: They all are closed right, POSTMAN checks and will not approve wrong Request - red marks available

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "roles":  
        [
            {
                "role_id": "TEST1",
                "role_name": "Для тестов"
            },
            {
                "role_id": "TEST3",
                "role_name": "Для тестов
            }
        ]
}
```